# How to eveluate $\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\tan^4x+\tan^2x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to Evaluate $$\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\tan^4x+\tan^2x}dx=?$$

My try:

let $\tan x=t$, $\sec^2x\ dx=dt$, $dx=\frac{dt}{t^2+1}$
$$\int\frac{(t^2+1)^2}{t^4+t^2}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}$$
$$\int\frac{(t^2+1)}{t^4+t^2}dt$$
$$\int\frac{t^2}{t^4+t^2}dt+\int \frac{1}{t^4+t^2}dt$$
$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2+1}+\int \frac{dt}{t^2(t^2+1)}$$
First integration can be evaluated but I don't know how to evaluate second integral. Should I use partial fraction?please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Factor out $\tan^2x$ from denominator & use $\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$, $$\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\tan^4x+\tan^2x}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\tan^2x(\tan^2x+1)}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\tan^2x(\sec^2x)}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^2x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{d(\tan x)}{\tan^2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an alternative approach for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sec^{4}(x)}{\tan^{4}(x) + \tan^{2}(x)} = \frac{1}{\sin^{4}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x)} = \frac{1}{\sin^{2}(x)} = \csc^{2}(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: that's nice. can't i evaluate by partial fractions?

Comment: You don't need to. Notice that the derivative of $\cot(x)$ is $-\csc^{2}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your substitution is correct. But in second line, you can factor out $t^2$ from the denominator & proceed as follows
$$\int \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+t^2}dt=\int\frac{t^2+1}{t^2(t^2+1)}dt=\int \frac{dt}{t^2}=-\frac1t+C$$